# Wrapper with WKWebView - Load ALL links within WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

`WKWebView` allows you to open external links (those different from base url) via Safari.
However, sometimes you want to open ALL links within `WKWebView` itself.
For instance, say you have a base url `"https://trader.finmarkets.com"` but you have a link `"https://secure.transactions.finmarkets.com"`that you also want to open within the `WKWebView` without using UIApplication.shared.open(url) which will open externally.

The question is : 
`How do I wrap my website to open all links on the WKWebview?`
(of-course except email and telephone numbers)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if navigationAction.navigationType == .LinkActivated  {
        if let newURL = navigationAction.request.URL &&
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(newURL) &&
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(newURL) {
                print(newURL)
                print("User clicked on link. Open it internally.")
                decisionHandler(.Allow)
        } else {
            print("Cannot open URL")
        }
    } else {
        print("Not a user click")
    }
}
```

You may need to fiddle with this a little to get it to work perfectly, but I think it might be along the lines you're looking for.